# Another use case of funtools.partial in T5 tutorial code

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I was reading this code. From `T5` [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/master/notebooks/t5-trivia.ipynb).. I found this snippet.

```
def nq_dataset_fn(split, shuffle_files=False):
  # We only have one file for each split.
  del shuffle_files

  # Load lines from the text file as examples.
  ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(nq_tsv_path[split])
  # Split each "<question>\t<answer>" example into (question, answer) tuple.
  ds = ds.map(
      functools.partial(tf.io.decode_csv, record_defaults=["", ""],
                        field_delim="\t", use_quote_delim=False),
      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  # Map each tuple to a {"question": ... "answer": ...} dict.
  ds = ds.map(lambda *ex: dict(zip(["question", "answer"], ex)))
  return ds
```

What did I understand reading this? Well, `functools.partial` is used for creating a wrapper around some known to manipulate the arguments or to reduce the number of arguments, but what is the use case here? It is confusing, given that we could simply call `tf.io.decode_csv`?

Comment: It's providing additional arguments, no? `functools.partial(tf.io.decode_csv, record_defaults=["", ""], field_delim="\t", use_quote_delim=False)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.: No. These arguments were there in `tf.io.decode_csv` itself. So we could have just called it instead of going through this hassle.

Comment: What do you mean "they are already there", you mean they are already the default values?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.: I mean the function decode csv take those parameters. No need to create another function which will basically take same parameters as before.

Comment: That isn't what `partial` does... it *partially applies* arguments, not "creates" new ones... that doesn't even really make sense. Your question is basically "what does partial do", because I don't think you actually undertand what it does. If you provided just `tf.io.decode_csv` it wouldn't use the correct arguments, because it would only use the default ones. By using partial, you've created a callable that uses the ones that are being passed to partial.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.: I said so checking this link. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map